# Create alias/modify path from Python script

Tags: python, bash, terminal, zsh

I'm working on a command-line application and I would like, when running the setup.py script after downloading the application files, for an alias to be created permanently (i.e. not just for this terminal session) for the program. The problem I'm running into is, if the user is using zsh, for example, then I need to add it to .zshrc, but it's different if the user is using bash, etc. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brute force (ugly) way:

```
#!/bin/sh
for user in joe sally bob
do
    cd "/home/$user"
    [ -f .bashrc ] && echo "alias whatever" >>.bashrc
    [ -f .zshrc ] && echo "alias zversion" >>.zshrc
done
```

A more elegant way would be to have a single system file for aliases, e.g. `/etc/aliases.local`, and modify the users' startup files once to source it. Also, add the `source /etc/aliases.local` line into the appropriate files in `/etc/skel` so that newly created users will get it automatically.

Or, better yet, on many distributions, there is a common file, `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc` or similar, that is sourced on startup.  Just make the modifications there.  Then, no modifications to users' personal startup files are needed.  (Zsh may very well have something similar.)

Comment: `cd ~"$user"` won't work, since tilde expansion occurs before parameter expansion. The tilde will be passed literally to the `cd` command, not expanded to the given user's home directory.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @John1024 is this the standard way of handling this?

Comment: @user43228 What you are asking for is nonstandard.  The standard way would be to create a shell script to do whatever the alias was going to do and put the script somewhere on the usual PATH.